# PHP 7 best/concise way to pass both key and value to a function

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have a query as to if something can be improved.

I have an array with keys and values.

I want to pass these keys and values into a function with each row as separate entities.

array example:

> ```
> [basket][products] {
>     [10] => 3 
>     [12] => 5
>     [15] => 1
>   }
> ```

I currently use:

```
    foreach($data['basket']['products'] as $product => $quantity) {
        $basketClass->addItem($product,$quantity);
    }
    unset($product,$quantity);
```

Which is 4 lines.

I don't want to *change* the values in the array simply I want to apply them all to the `->addItem` function row by row.

Is there a shorter, more concise or "cleaner" way of doing this, with particular emphesis on new PHP7 abilities?

Comment: shorter than 3 lines ? :D

Comment: *four lines. Foreach leaves values left over that should be tidied up.

Comment: 3 lines, because `{}` can be removed (-;

Comment: my comment was kind of polemic ;) but imho thats a matter of personal opinion - take a look @this reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1uuc34/quick_test_to_see_if_array_walk_is_better_than/ - if  this little difference according to performance doesn't concern you, you can try `array_walk`of course - as already mentioned in the answers

Comment: It's not less code (actually more), but you could restructure it? `$basketClass->addItemsFromArray($data['basket']['products'])` and then perform the loop/array_walk there (having an unset would be unnecessary as it's localised to the scope of that function). Results in additional code, but would reduce this portion to a single line ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Seems like micro-optimisation to me, but you must have a reason to wanting to make it tidier, so i'd just say move the processing to somewhere else.

Comment: @sintakonte that's quite a notable speed difference... hmm

Comment: @MLeFevre I had considered that option as well, after posting the question. However I am curious in principle if there's a *neater* way to apply values + keys to a function. Thanks

Comment: If the array is in this format [  [10, 3], [12, 3], ... ], then there is one liner php code :D

Comment: huh... pseudo optimizations...

Comment: @Neodan there is a factor of that, yes. I'm mostly curious that in lager more complex situations if there's an easier (newer) method.

Comment: @invisal please put it as an answer. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't going to many "shorter" ways of doing this, short of just cramming more code onto a single line, but you might find it neater to use `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($data['basket']['products'], function($quantity, $product) use($basketClass) {
  $basketClass->addItem($product, $quantity);
});
```

This won't modify the array itself, and doesn't require you to unset any variables afterwards. See https://eval.in/909861 for an example.

Ultimately this is a matter of personal opinion though.

Comment: Yeah as you say it's down to personal opinion; I find `array_walk` to be less tidy but was curious if the community knew any (tidy) shortcuts.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. For me, a standard loop is always going to be more readable. If it's just the left-over variables afterwards that's an issue, then you can safely just leave them in scope - it'll generally only ever cause an issue if you're looping over by reference. Either you never use them again, or you overwrite them with something else.

Comment: I see with array_walk the variables get tidied up which is a plus, in my view. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_walk`

```
array_walk($data['basket']['products'], function($quantity, $product) use($basketClass) { 
 $basketClass->addItem($product,$quantity);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I had looked at `array_walk` but had perceived to be less "tidy" (but this is totally subjective)

Comment: It is possible, but for my taste it seems to me a more readable code, but it is totally subjective :)

Comment: Yeah there is a factor of trading readability for conciseness, but thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks ugly, but it works.

```
$a = $data['basket']['products'];
array_map(
   "call_user_func", 
   array_fill(0, count($a), array($basketClass, "addItem")), 
   array_keys($a), array_values($a)
);
```

Well, if you remove the line, it will be one line.

```
array_map("call_user_func", array_fill(0, count($a), array($basketClass, "addItem")), array_keys($a), array_values($a));
```